# C++ object with members for an asio get method

Tags: c++, class, member, ostream

I want to implement a class in which members match this function:

```
int get(
  string &host_,
  string &port_, 
  string url_path,
  ostream &out_,
  vector<string> &headers, 
  unsigned int timeout
  )
```

I have this:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include "Register.h"

using namespace std;

class Request : public Register {

private:
string *host;
string *port;
string *url;
ostream *out;
vector<string> *header;
unsigned int *timeout;

public:
Request() {
  this -> host = new string();
  this -> port = new string();
  this -> url = new string();
  this -> out = new ostream();
  this -> header = new vector<string>();
  this -> timeout = new int();
}
```

But I´m not able to instantiate it.  What's up with the ostream for example:

```
this -> out = new ostream();
```

I'm still new to c++ and now I´m completely confused, and I couldn't find the correct answer on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::ostream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream) is a base class for specific stream implementations, like [`std::ofstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream), you cannot directly instantiate it.

In C++, unlike in Java, we don't allocate everything on the heap, but prefer *value semantics*:

```
/// Can be easily copied
class HoldSomething {
private:
    std::string name;
    std::vector<std::string> values;
public:
    /// constructors
    HoldSomething() : name(), values() {}
    explicit HoldSomething( const std::string& name ) :
        name( name ), values() {}
    /// modifiers
    void addValue( const std::string& val ) {
        value.push_back( val );
    }
...
```

Comment: what exactly does the name(), values() ??

Comment: These are constructor calls for member variables. See updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You're confused between a reference and a pointer I think.  The function takes references like vector &headers, string &host_, etc.  Your class stores pointers which are not the same thing.

If you pass a variable into a function normally, (no * or & in the signature) then you create a copy of the thing you pass in.  This is "pass-by-copy".  If you pass in a pointer (*), you're passing something that points to the memory address of the variable that you want to use.  Technically you're passing the pointer by copy, but it points to the same thing so you're okay.  If you pass in a reference (&), then you're aliasing the variable from the scope where the function is called.  You're saying "I want to treat this variable like I would in pass by copy, except I want the changes to apply to the one originally passed into the function as well from the outer scope".

So, your class can contain normal members instead:

```
private:
string host;
string port;
string url;
ostream out;
vector<string> header;
unsigned int timeout;
```

That way you can pass them directly to the function without an issue.  They will also be default constructed in this case so you don't need to use "new" or do anything.  In fact, you wouldn't even need to write a constructor.

Mind, you probably need an accessor function to let you modify all of these since you made them private, or you'll need to make your constructor take parameters so you can give the data members useful values before using the structure.

**PS:** You want to use std::ofstream instead for your output :)  Check out the following example at the link below:

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 0):

You should post errors you are getting. `std::ostream` is only the interface; you can't instatiate it.

Answer (score 0):

std::ostream is just an interface
You can initialise "out" pointer by "std::cout" or another concrete object thats derives from std::ostream. For example:

```
out = &std::cout;
```

or

```
std::ofstream file("file.txt");
out = &file;
```

By the way, it is a bad idea to use plain pointers. Try any smart pointer such as std::shared_ptr or std::unique_ptr.